# Can I have a SSL certificate for direct IP access?

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, web-hosting, certificate, encryption

Is it possible to have a SSL certificate for access directly to an IP, and not through a hostname? Eg, can I purchase an SSL certificate to make https://1.2.3.4/ work without giving a security warning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible and several CAs will issue certificates to IP addresses. You will somehow have to demonstrate that you own or control the IP address.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't actually tried this, but I assume that if you create a Certificate Signing Request (CSR) with the Common name of `1.2.3.4` it should at least generate.

Whether or not a web browser will accept it is a different story, but if you're accessing the resources via something other than a web browser then your milage may vary.

Comment: I can confirm it's possible, and will be accepted. Now getting a real CA to rubberstamp the CSR, that's going to be another story. I don't know of any CA that will do it.